# How to set min-height using css

Tags: css

Guys could you help me please? My site is http://letsforum.com/ and I have a problem with content height sometimes when there is not enough content it doesn't show 100%, my question is how to set **.content** to have **min-height: 100%;**

Please visit help pages here and take a look **./help.php**

Comment: Have you tried something that didn't work? If so what was it?

Comment: paste you code here...

Comment: Is it .content or #content ?

Comment: It's "#content" sorry it works with min-height: 500px; but doesn't work with %. #content {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    width: auto !important;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to keep your footer at the bottom, there are a few tricks out there.
Looking at your 404 page, I'm guessing that is what you're talking about.

Take a look at these examples:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Sorry, I can only currently post two links.

Another suggestion: May not work with all browsers:

You'd need to Update your HTML files so that the Closing div for Container is actually BEFORE the Footer DIV (and make the CSS changes below)... 
eg;

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">
    ....
    ....
   </div>
   <div id="content">
   ....
   ....
   </div>
**</div>** <-- This one was previously below the closing DIV for the footer.
<div id="footer">
....
....
</div>
```

And then you would update your global.css:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
 }

#content {
 background: #fff;
 width: auto !important;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 overflow: auto;  /*change this */
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 padding-bottom: 20px; /* add this */
}


/* Add this footer section */

#footer {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: -20px;
 height: 20px;
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, you right it just shows like half page. I have tried that and doesn't work please could you give it a try and tell me if it works or not please

Comment: If either of those suggestions do not work for you, search with your favorite search engine: float footer to bottom - you're sure to find an example that will suit your needs. I don't believe there is a silver bullet for this particular problem, but there are many solutions roughly based on the same concept. I ran into a similar issue recently and I used the negative margin solution - suited my needs.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer above. I tested it, and it works for me. Might need tweaks for some older and less common browsers.

Comment: I can find this **</div>** <-- This one was previously below the closing DIV for the footer.

Comment: It is between these lines in the raw HTML output of your 404 page that I was testing with:

<!-- The following piece of code allows MyBB to run scheduled tasks. DO NOT REMOVE --><!-- End task image code -->

</div>
<!-- Lazy Share Buttons Start -->
<script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Where should I move this </div>?

Comment: move it just above the <div id="footer">.....
as in: </div><div id="footer"> - get what I mean?

Comment: Thanks but "Powered By MyBB...." is affected I mean it just moved to the right!

Comment: Is there somewhere I can see what you are working on?

Comment: I have not changed anything this is how this theme was made but as you can see it has THING that I would like to change but it looks like pain in the ***

Comment: I don't think I understand..... You just said: the powered by mybb just moved to the right... Where did that happen, can I see this somewhere to take a look?

Comment: I am testing it on localhost sorry forget to mention it. P.S. I only have to apply your fix or also from those 2 links?

Comment: Only my suggestion should be needed.... Given it's myBB, chances are that there a few files involved for the HTML generation maybe a footer.php file and a few others. I don't have myBB currently installed anywhere so it's very hard to know where you are modifying.... What version, and what theme are you using?

Comment: Thanks very much Apart 1 theme and MYBB 1.6.11